# Parallel logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, parallel-computing

I need to perform stepwise binary logistic regression (The horror! The horror!) on 1.5 million observations.  This takes far too long in SAS, so I'm wondering if I can use R to process it in a multicore environment.  Apparently package gmulti (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i12/paper) will do the trick, but it's not clear to me if it will do that outside of its genetic algorithm.  That still might work for me, but I don't have a large number of variables (about 30) so it's not necessary.  As long as the results of the brute force and ga approach could be assured to be similar, then I might try it.  However, I see others have had problems getting the parallel feature to run: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-April/351820.html.  Any other suggestions 
on how to parallelize logistic regression in R?  A web search turned up a couple of papers, but not much that seemed specific to R.  And please spare me a lecture about stepwise regression-I'm very well aware of the pitfalls.  I'm replicating someone else's analysis.  I'm using a Windows 64 bit system.

Answer (score 6):

In data analysis you typically don't want to reinvent the wheel

There are packages to do this in R namely: [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/biglm.pdf)

sorry that is for linear regression.

GLM with large data sets can be fit with [speedglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/speedglm.pdf)

```
install.packages('speedglm')
library(speedglm)
set.seed(123)
trt <- c(rep(1,500000),rep(0,500000))
x <- matrix( rnorm(1000000*29), ncol=29)
beta <- c(10,rep(1,29))
y <- exp(cbind(trt,x) %*% beta)/(1+exp(cbind(trt,x) %*% beta))>0.5

data <- data.frame(y=y,trt=trt,x=x)

m <- speedglm(y~trt+x, data,family=binomial())
```

Comment: @Benjamin-very interesting, but I don't think it will do stepwise regression.

Comment: `biglm` can do generalized linear models too. Using either package you can code a stepwise routine.

Comment: why these two packages are fast? it uses advanced optimization algorithm?

Comment: As far as I can tell, speedglm does not actually use multiple cores